# Prevent Nano from creating .save files?

Tags: editors, nano

I have a problem with the `Nano` editor. If it ever exits unexpectedly, it leaves behind `.save` files, which are just versions of the edits I was making.  Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

From [Nano's man](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.1.html#NOTES)

> In some cases nano will try to dump the buffer into an emergency file.
>   This will happen mainly if nano receives a SIGHUP or SIGTERM or runs
>   out of memory. It will write the buffer into a file named nano.save if
>   the buffer didn’t have a name already, or will add a ".save" suffix to
>   the current filename. If an emergency file with that name already
>   exists in the current directory, it will add ".save" plus a number
>   (e.g. ".save.1") to the current filename in order to make it unique.
>   In multibuffer mode, nano will write all the open buffers to their
>   respective emergency files.

So, it is a nano emergency file where its buffer gets dumped. The flag −F (−−multibuffer) would enable multiple file buffers, if available. The flag −R (−−restricted) or restricted mode, will guide Nano to not read or write to any file not specified on the command line; read any nanorc files; allow suspending; allow a file to be appended to, prepended to, or saved under a different name if it already has one; or use backup files or spell checking. Also accessible by invoking nano with any name beginning with ’r’ (e.g. "rnano").

Comment: Is there a way to do it without all those other limitations?

Comment: Dear @Levi H. yes, per the response bove, use `nano -R` when you call it from terminal

Comment: that won't work, I asked if I could use it without the other limitations you posted above...

Answer (score 1):

The `-R` / `--restricted` option will disable saves (as well as some other features):

> Restricted mode: don't read or write to any file not specified on the command line; read
>    any  nanorc  files;  allow  suspending; allow a file to be appended to, prepended to, or
>   saved under a different name if it already has one; or use backup files or spell  checking.
>    Also accessible by invoking **nano** with any name beginning with 'r' (e.g.  "rnano")